# Optimal way of having multiple BETWEEN condition on the same column

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to optimize a BigQuery query time complexity that has multiple `BETWEEN` conditions on the same column?

Query example:

```
SELECT time, value
FROM `table`
WHERE ((time between "2019-04-06 20:40:00" AND "2019-04-07 21:00:00")
    OR (time between "2020-05-04 17:12:06" AND "2020-05-04 17:37:36")
    OR (time between "2019-01-16 15:10:00" AND "2019-01-16 15:45:00")
    OR (time between "2020-04-09 20:55:36" AND "2020-04-09 21:01:36")
    OR (time between "2019-07-08 10:05:00" AND "2019-07-08 10:45:00")
    OR (time between "2021-06-07 20:02:32" AND "2021-06-07 20:30:56")
    OR (time between "2019-11-03 14:55:20" AND "2019-11-03 15:17:24"))
```

There are more `between` conditions in the real query (around 60).

The full table contains `>3TB` of data

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
WITH time_ranges as (
  select timestamp '2019-04-06 20:40:00' start_time, timestamp '2019-04-07 21:00:00' end_time union all
  select '2020-05-04 17:12:06', '2020-05-04 17:37:36' union all
  select '2019-01-16 15:10:00', '2019-01-16 15:45:00' union all
  select '2020-04-09 20:55:36', '2020-04-09 21:01:36' union all
  select '2019-07-08 10:05:00', '2019-07-08 10:45:00' union all
  select '2021-06-07 20:02:32', '2021-06-07 20:30:56' union all
  select '2019-11-03 14:55:20', '2019-11-03 15:17:24'     
)
SELECT time, value
FROM your_table
WHERE (
  SELECT LOGICAL_OR(time between start_time and end_time)
  FROM time_ranges
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It, indeed, slowed the process drastically. With the original query it gives results in ~10 seconds with, while with the suggested approach it went up to 1 min 40 sec.

Comment: Yea. I would expected this. Somehow I thought you are looking toward eliminating of complexity and redundancy in query code ... and make it more manageable - obviously there is a price for it :o(

Comment: thanks for your input and sorry for the late reply. I highly appreciate the time that you put in this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to save your criteria into a table?

If your time windows are non-overlapping, you could try a cross join and filter:

```
select time, value
from your_table
cross join time_windows
where time between start_time and end_time
```

where `time_windows` would something like

```
start_time,            end_time
'2019-04-06 20:40:00' | '2019-04-07 21:00:00'
'2020-05-04 17:12:06' | '2020-05-04 17:37:36'
etc...
```

with both fields already saved as timestamps.

A cross join against a 3TB table *should* be reasonably quick if this is the actual complexity of the query.  Adding in other joins and filters could also slow it down.

Additionally, if you are able to modify your table to be partitioned on the `time` column, BQ might be able to optimize your query even more.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The timestamps are not constant and get changed often. This might be a temporary workaround but not a long time solution as the product might run on different timestamps in parallel and with this solution it will need to create a temporary table for each run